# Creating objects from resultset. Am I doing this right?

Tags: java, jdbc, resultset

I'm studying Java, and I'm learning JDBC right now. I think I have a handle on how to use a resultset object, but I'd  like to make sure I'm doing it right.

See the code below. It queries a table named "menu" in a database named "restaurant". The table has four columns:

- *id_menu*  Integer, the primary key for the table.
- *name* String, the name of the menu item (ex. "Double cheeseburger")
- *descr* String, a description of the menu item (ex. "Two all-beef patties on a whole wheat bun.")
- *price* Double, the price of the item (ex. 5.95) (note I know I could use Money type, but I'm trying to keep it simple)

Here's the Java code for a menuItem object. Each row in the table should be used to create a menuItem object:

```
public class menuItem {

    public int id = 0;
    public String descr = "";
    public Double price = 0.0;
    public String name = "";
    public menuItem(int newid, String newdescr, Double newprice, String newname){
        id = newid;
        descr = newdescr;
        price = newprice;
        name = newname;
        }
    }
```

Everything is public just to simplify this exercise.

Here's the code to populate the database. At the moment, this code is a method inside the main class.

```
public static ArrayList<menuItem> reQuery() throws ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, SQLException{    

    ArrayList<menuItem> mi = new ArrayList<menuItem>();

    //Step 1. User Class.forname("").newInstance() to load the database driver.
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();

    //Step 2. Create a connection object with DriverManager.getConnection("")
    //Syntax is jdbc:mysql://server/database? + user=username&password=password
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/miguelel_deliveries?" + "user=root&password=");

    //Step 3. Create a statement object with connection.createStatement();
    Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();

    //Step 4. Create variables and issue commands with the Statement object.
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("Select * from menu");

    //Step 5. Iterate through the ResultSet. Add a new menuItem object to mi for each item.
    while(rs.next()){
    menuItem item = new menuItem(rs.getInt("id_menu"),rs.getString("descr"),rs.getDouble("price"),rs.getString("name"));
    mi.add(item);
    }
    return mi;
}
```

This code works. I end up with an ArrayList of menuItem's, so that each element corresponds to one row in the table. But is this the best way? Can I generalize this into a way of handling ResultSets?

1. For each table or view in the database, create a Java class with properties equivalent to the table's columns.
2. Load the tables contents into a ResultSet object.
3. Using *while(ResultSet.next())* to iterate through the ResultSet, create a new object (from the class) in step 1 for each item in the ResultSet.
4. As each new object is created, add it to an ArrayList of the class.
5. Manipulate the ArrayList as needed.

Is this an efficient method? Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: This belongs on [codereview.se]


Comment: Thanks. I didn't know Code Review was even there. I prepared 3 other questions that were all, "This code works, but is it the best way", like this one. I'll post them on Code Review rather than Stack Overflow. Feel free to close this question, and thanks again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code logic is fine, but the implementation has several problems:

- it doesn't respect naming conventions. Classes start with an uppercase letter
- you shouldn't use public fields. And initializing fields to default values is useless if they're reinitialized right after by the constructor
- you don't close the connection, which means that each time the method is executed, it will leave one connection open, resulting in memory being consumer for nothing, and your program eventually failing due to the max number of open connections being reached. The connection should be closed in a finally block, or using the try-with-resources construct available since Java 7. ResultSets and statements should also be closed, although not closing them is not as problematic as not closing the connection.
- the Class.forName().newInstance() should not be necessary with a recent enough driver and JVM
- the chosen types are bizarre. The price, for example, is stored in a nullable Double variable. But you use getDouble(), which will never return null, to get its value. Also, using double for a price is a bad choice. Use a BigDecimal instead.
- using `select *` is a bad practice. Select the columns you want, and not all the columns.

I would not generalize the creation of a class per table. Many times, you won't query for all the columns from a single table, but for some column of several joined tables.

I would also consider using an ORM (JPA) instead of doing JDBC. This will make your code much cleaner, shorter, readable and safer.

Comment: Thank you very much. These comments are very helpful. Responding:    I renamed menuItem to MenuItem.  I'll change the public properties to private and add getter method (I imagine I wont need setters?  When closing, do I need to close the Connection, the Statement, and the ResultSet? Or will conn.close() close the Statement and ResultSet?  I commented out the Class.forName().newInstace() line, and the code behaved identically. I wonder why my Java textbook (Big Java, 4th Edition, from 2010) says it's required.  Thanks again for the very helpful comments.

Comment: It was required, a long time ago. Now there is a mechanism that allows a jar to define a JDBC driver and register it with the driver manager without needing any code. Closing the connection is essential. Closing the two others as soon as you don't need them anymore is a good practice. In real code, you sometimes open several statements and resultsets on the same connection. Closing them frees memory and other resources.